# The error "ree.module.js:21749 Uncaught TypeError: Invalid value used as weak map key" occurs in the three.js project

Tags: javascript, three.js

[image]
This error occurred while making glass material with three.js.
After a few seconds of execution, the screen turns black and an error occurs.

```
import * as THREE from 'three'

export class Glass
{
    constructor(scene, renderer)
    {
        this.currentScene = scene
        this.renderer = renderer
        this.setupModel()
    }

    setupModel()
    {
        const boxRenderTarget = new THREE.WebGLCubeRenderTarget(1024, {
            format: THREE.RGBFormat,
            generateMipmaps: true,
            minFilter: THREE.LinearMipmapLinearFilter
        });

        boxRenderTarget._pmremGen = new THREE.PMREMGenerator(this.renderer);

        const boxCamera = new THREE.CubeCamera(0.01, 10, boxRenderTarget);

        const boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();

        const boxMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial({
            color: 0xffffff,
            metalness: .1,
            roughness: 0.05,
            ior: 2.5,
            thickness: 0.2,
            transmission: 1,
            side: THREE.DoubleSide,
            envMap: boxRenderTarget.texture,
            envMapIntensity: 1,
        });

        const box = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeometry, boxMaterial);
        box.position.set(0, 0.5, -20)
        box.scale.set(1, 2, 1)
        box.add(boxCamera)
        this.currentScene.add(box)
        this.box = box;
    }

    update()
    {
        if(this.box)
        {
            this.box.visible = false

            const boxCamera = this.box.children[0]
            boxCamera.update(this.renderer, this.currentScene)

            const renderTarget = boxCamera.renderTarget._pmremGen.fromCubemap(
                boxCamera.renderTarget.texture);

            this.box.material.envMap = renderTarget.texture;
            this.box.material.needsUpdate = true;

            this.box.visible = true
        }
    }
}
```

For the above code, after setting the model, update envMap through the update function to obtain glass material.
Maybe "this.box.material.envMap = renderTarget.texture;" I think I'm getting an error here, how do I fix it?